# Invoke common class method on a list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects:

```
var objs = new List<object> {
    new A(1),
    new B(2,3),
    new C()
};
```

I would like to execute a common class method (`calculate()`) on each object. Something like this:

```
foreach(var o in objs)
{ 
    o.Calculate();
    //or
    o.invoke("Calculate");
}
```

I know I can accomplish this using class names and method names and reflection, but is there a way to do it similar to how its described above?

Edit: the `Calculate()` is defined in each class.

Comment: Where is that method defined?

Comment: Do `A`, `B` and `C` have a common base class or interface with a `Calculate` method?

Comment: Sounds like the perfect use case for an interface

Comment: You could use `List<dynamic>` and handle the times when calling `o.Calculate()` fails if the method is missing.

Comment: As per your code - no. Because the type of `o` in your `foreach` is `Object` and therefore you can only access the properties and methods of the Object type on it. You either have to cast it, use reflection to check for a method, or else use a common base class / interface for A, B and C. Would really help if you could clarify if you really must use `object` or whether using `dynamic`or better yet a base class  / interface, is an option for you.

Comment: It really sounds like you should be using a common base class or interface that includes the "Calculate()" method.

Comment: @Sean Changing the type from object to dynamic did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: `dynamic` won't save you from runtime errors though. The compiler will indeed allow you to add any object without a `Calculate()` method to the `List<dynamic>`, but your code will fail at runtime if there is no such method defined on the object.

Comment: You should address that in your answer @mm8. It's a great point and baffles me why you'd take the `dynamic` approach here when this is the exact thing that inheritance/interfaces were designed to solve. It's like pounding a screw into wood with a hammer. Does it work? Usually, but it's not really the right tool for the job.

Comment: @CodeStranger: I added this to my answer.

Comment: Use an interface, perfectly fits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A`, `B` and `C` should either derive from a common base class or implement an interface where the `Calculate()` method is declared:

```
public class CommonBase
{
    public virtual int Calculate() => 0;
}

public class A : CommonBase
{
    public override int Calculate() => 1;
} 

...
```

You can then change the type from `List<object>` to `List<YourInterfaceType>` and call the method on all objects without doing any casting or reflection:

```
foreach(var o in objs)
{ 
    o.Calculate();
}
```

Edit: The use of the `dynamic` keyword won't save you from runtime errors. The compiler will indeed allow you to add any object without a `Calculate()` method to a `List<dynamic>`, but your code will fail at runtime if there is no such method defined on the object.

Comment: This indeed was better than just changing the type to dynamic, Thanks!